# Can we deduce that two rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ are isomorphic if their polynomial ring are isomorphic?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Given two rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ (with or without identity: it's not specified). If $R_1[x]$ is isomorphic to $R_2[y]$ (No such requirement that the isomorphism sends the constant terms to constant terms), can we deduce that $R_1 \cong R_2$?

I feel there might be a counterexample but it's quite hard to find one.

Comment: This is the cancellation problem of Zariski. There are many counterexamples. See http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/Lip.text.pdf

Comment: This (interesting) question has received many good answers on math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/does-rx-cong-sx-imply-r-cong-s.  I have voted to close it here as "no longer relevant".

Comment: See also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0483v2.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was recently asked and answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/does-rx-cong-sx-imply-r-cong-s
As answered there, it is possible to find two non-isomorphic commutative rings whose polynomial rings in one variable are isomorphic.
An example is given in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/home.html

Answer (score 5):

Let X be an affine variety with two non-isomorphic vector bundles V and W that become isomorphic after adding a trivial line bundle to each.  Then the coordinate rings of the total spaces of V and W should yield a counterexample.   (Though you might have to do some extra work to verify that the total spaces of V and W are non-isomorphic as varieties.)

The counterexample cited by Tobias takes X to be the 2-sphere, V the tangent bundle to X, and W the trivial plane bundle over X.